# How to bake bread and desserts without an oven?

Tags: baking, bread, dessert

Preface: I already read [Is it possible to bake a cake without an oven?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/22889/24882) and [Baking pizza without an oven](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/43005/24882).

The package of many prearranged, UNcooked **frozen flour products** presuppose the use of an electric or microwave oven. However, how can these desserts be cooked without them?
I have available an electric stovetop, pans, and also a rice cooker.

I exemplify **frozen flour products** with the following: [ACE Bakery Frozen Bake Your Own™ Baguettes, Flatbreads, Focaccia](http://www.acebakery.com/bake-your-own/)   and [Waitrose Frozen Cheesecakers, Pies, Tarts](http://www.waitrose.com/shop/Browse/Groceries/Frozen/Frozen_Desserts).

Comment: should frozen be in the title since that is the main distinguisher between the questions you link to?

Comment: @MHH Thanks. I wish to ask about both frozen and fresh products.

Comment: A method used on sailboats for baking bread without an oven, is to use a pressure cooker on a stove top. Google should have examples/instructions/recipes.

Comment: There is a method of building an oven out of baking stone and clay pot. Or you can use dutch oven with a brick or stone on the bottom – the idea here is to distribute heat all around, not only on the bottom. That's the idea behind any oven and clay and rock are the best at that, they have been used for millennia before our gas or electric ovens.

Answer (score 1):

From your list of 'electric stovetop, pots, and rice cooker' I would suggest constructing a double boiler by placing one pot inside another where the inner pot has a lid and the outer pot has a measure of water sufficient to support the inner pot (a steel bowl would be preferable, but you didn't mention that). Using a low heat (just enough to bring the water to a boil). Place your product inside and be prepared to wait. The double boiler will closely resemble oven like convection to evenly (albeit slowly) heat your food. It should brown well and you minimize the risk of burning. If you are making something like a small pizza, you should definitely add a small bit of oil/butter to the bottom of the inner pan.

Do you have access to a ['slow cooker' (crock pot)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003HF6PUO)? These can be used to create a variety of 'baked' goods (breads, pizza, cakes...) But I am guessing not (because you didn't list it...) However, you do mention a 'rice cooker' which is not that different (depending on the brand/style) and I would be inclined to experiment with that.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of peace corp volunteers in Africa baking cakes on outdoor charcoal fires. It takes some patience but it works!

Here's an example of how it can be done: http://www.oliviaprentzel.com/blog/2016/3/31/how-to-make-a-peace-corps-oven

You might be able to jerry-rig the steps to do it on an electric stove top.

Answer (score -2):

Fairly simple:

Assuming using a standard round cake pan

1. Take a large pot that can fit a cake pan; and put on stove with lid; heat for about 5 mins on low/med.
2. Insert a wire rack or some other flameproof device that will hold your cake or baking pan up at least 1 inch from bottom.
3. Insert cake pan and cover; cook about 40 mins; until knife comes out clean

Comment: I've tried this before, as a poor student in a tiny dorm room without an oven. It never worked for me, but it ruined my large pot.

Comment: not sure i understand how; but thanks for downvote.  Its fairly simple; heat in object until its 350; it's really no different the oven.  I've used successfully over campfires for years.   Using a cheap pot would result in failure.

Comment: @rumtscho can you elaborate.

Comment: @MHH there isn't much to elaborate. The food didn't bake, but the outer pot was burnt on the bottom.

Comment: it burned on the bottom?  Either you didn't lift cake off the surface at least 1 inch or you used a extremely thin pan.  cast iron would be the best bet.